# Iframe link part is showing first on page loading in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have made a simple site and added a link inside iframe tag in middle of the site(inside raw html element). my issue is that, when I am loading the page , the page should open from the top but in my case the page is scrolled to middle of the page and shows the area of iframe.
I want my page open from the top as all sites are open.
please do suggest. thanks in advance

Comment: did you added any hashtag in src of iframe like  "domain.com/url#test"

Comment: @charan kumar No. my iframe is like this.....<iframe height="396" width="300px" src="https://b1g1.com/frontgivingbghbwidget/mywidget/pgSKofJkNGDYQbcb7HQTrVQKYzPM20SZXAm"></iframe>

Comment: somewhere in js, cursor in focused on page load to the input field in the external site which you placed in your src. Thats why it is hitting input field on page load. If you can edit the external site, then you can resolve it

Comment: is there any solution for it?

Comment: is the site placed in src accessible for you? means are you able to edit that site?

Comment: yes. I can edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179868/discussion-between-sibasankar-bhoi-and-charan-kumar).